# Table View's Delegate Method Cell for row at not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

I am using a table view and set the delegate and datasource in view will appear.
return 1 in number of section and 5 in number of rows but cell for row at delegate method is not called. I checked my storyboard view cell's ideantifier and class name is correct. Pls help

Comment: Show the code you currently have.

Comment: Can you show your code , plz  ?

Comment: check your tableview's height, is it zero?

Comment: You shouldn't set the delegate and datasource inside your `viewWillAppear` method, this will cause them to be set every time the view controller is going to be displayed. You should set them inside your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Make sure that data source and delegate is connected in **Interface Builder** > Connections Inspector (⌥⌘6). This is much better than doing it in code.

Comment: Have you checked that the ViewController Custom Class is set correctly in Interface Builder - i.e. to the class where you are putting your code?

Comment: yes by break points i am sure about it

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding 5 into your numberOfRowsInSection func?

Comment: no nick but my array count is 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that may be or are wrong with your code. First one is that you should setup the delegate in storyboard or **ViewDidLoad** (in storyboard drag from tableView to the ViewController instance and select both - delegate and datasource) The other thing is that you may made a typo when writing the code for delegate methods(always use automatic method completion feature in xcode)

Answer (score 0):

After setting delegate and datasource , reload the table view.